# Why can't I run multiple files through a `while read` loop?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, scripts, files

I want to run this command in 180 files:

```
cat kegg_random.tsv | while read line ; do
    echo "$line" | join -1 2 -2 1 -e"NA" -o1.1,0,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5 -t $'\t' - kegg_sort_2020.out | shuf -n1 >> RM1_randomKO.tsv
  done
```

How I do that?
I tried to run in `bash`, but something is wrong:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.txt; do 
  cat "$f" | while read line ; do 
  echo "$line" | 
  join -1 2 -2 1 -e"NA" -o1.1,0,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5 -t $'\t' - kegg_sort_2020.out | 
  shuf -n1 > "${f%.tsv}" 
done

line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Missing the 2nd `done`, so the `for` loop gets confused.  Fix:

```
for f in *.txt; do 
  while read line ; do 
      echo "$line" | 
      join -1 2 -2 1 -e"NA" -o1.1,0,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5 -t $'\t' - kegg_sort_2020.out | 
      shuf -n1 >> "${f%.tsv}" 
  done < "$f"
done
```

---

Notes:  [`cat` wasn't needed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat).  Beware of using `>` where `>>` is needed.

The logic of the above code seems a bit confused.  Using `join` on one line would only output one line.  Piping that one line to `shuf` is useless -- it's like trying to shuffle a "deck" of cards with just one card in it.  The `echo` isn't needed either.  The code could be simplified to:

```
for f in *.txt; do 
  while read line ; do 
      join -1 2 -2 1 -e"NA" -o1.1,0,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5 -t $'\t' \
        - kegg_sort_2020.out  <<<  "$line" 
  done < "$f"   >>  "${f%.tsv}"
done
```

Depending on the input file structures even `join` might be unnecessary.  A judicious `read` might be sufficient, either that or the `join` alone would be sufficient:

```
for f in *.txt; do 
      join -1 2 -2 1 -e"NA" -o1.1,0,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5 -t $'\t' \
        "$f" kegg_sort_2020.out
done >>  "${f%.tsv}"
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working =)

Comment: It's to get some information from the "kegg_sort_2020.out" table randomly, according to id number in the input files.

Comment: Well that usage of `shuf` would not be random.  Something like this might be more what was intended:  `join -1 2 -2 1 -e"NA" -o1.1,0,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5 -t $'\t'   -  <(shuf -n1 kegg_sort_2020.out)  <<<  "$line"`